# webpack config is not working for my scss files :(

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to make use of css modules and sass loader.  However, doesn't seem to be working.  Here is my webpack config - it doesn't throw any errors, but when I check `/static/` i only see bundle.js and not the style.scss.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    'index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: [
          'react-hot',
          'babel'
        ],
        include: path.join(__dirname, ''),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', ['css-loader', 'autoprefixer-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('/static/style.css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the filename only NOT the filepath (since it is based on publicPath)

```
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: [
          'react-hot',
          'babel'
        ],
        include: path.join(__dirname, ''),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader', 'autoprefixer-loader', 'sass-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Hello.  I tried this but still doesn't seem to be working.  The styles don't change at all